# Concurrency Thread Group plugin is not taken in Apache Jmeter 5.4.1 in windows OS

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

From https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-casutg

I downloaded Maven Artifact: kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-casutg:2.9 which has Concurrency Thread Group.

1. Then I copied jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.6 to Lib folder of Jmeter.
2. Also copied jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.9 to ext folder in Jmeter.

Then I restarted Jmeter and tried to add thread group but the Concurrency Thread Group option is  not there .

[image]

Comment: You need to download plugin manager and install plugins using its GUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps should work normally, most probably you made a mistake somewhere somehow, here are some Powershell commands which will install JMeter and the Custom Thread Groups bundle from scratch:

1. [Download JMeter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1)

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.4.1.zip -OutFile c:\temp\jmeter.zip
   ```
2. Download Custom Thread Groups plugin bundle

   ```
   Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://jmeter-plugins.org/files/packages/jpgc-casutg-2.9.zip -OutFile c:\temp\custom-thread-groups.zip
   ```
3. [Unpack JMeter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7.1)

   ```
   Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\temp\jmeter.zip' -DestinationPath c:\temp
   ```
4. Unpack the plugin:

   ```
   Expand-Archive -LiteralPath 'c:\temp\custom-thread-groups.zip' -DestinationPath c:\temp
   ```
5. [Copy the files to necessary locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1):

   ```
   Copy-Item -Path 'c:\temp\lib' -Destination 'C:\temp\apache-jmeter-5.4.1' -Recurse -Force
   ```
6. Launch JMeter

   ```
   C:\temp\apache-jmeter-5.4.1\bin\jmeter.bat
   ```

The custom thread groups should be there

P.S. wouldn't it be easier to use [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)?

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T, I'll check this and accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

After that, you need to go to Options -> Plugins Manager -> Select the plugins which you need and click on 'Apply Changes and Restart JMETER' button.